# Query if a date is between two other dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the code below, I am trying to run a query where a date has to be within a year determined by the local storage variable, 'name'. Since I only need results that are in the same YEAR as the one held in 'value', I separated the year, converted it to a string, and now that year is help in the variable 'string'.

```
   alert(value);

var cowid = localStorage.getItem('search_cowid');
//LSV contains the string that will not be modified
//search based on year--it is the one that is saved when the cow name is clicked on cow_history_search
//var dateyear = localStorage.getItem('name');
//LSV contains the year that will determine if is a match or not.
//I mapped the data to the 'where parameter 
///console.log(name);
///console.log("value = " + value);



var prestring = value;

//var string = prestring.toString("");

alert(prestring);

var beginning = "01"+ "/" + "01" + "/"+ prestring;
alert(beginning);

var end = "12"+ "/" + "31" + "/"+ prestring;
alert(end);


    var whereObject = 
        {"$and": [
            {"date": {"$gte": beginning} },
            {"date": {"$lte": end}} ,
            {"cow_id": cowid}
] };

    return JSON.stringify(whereObject);
```

Example:  the "value" is what would be in the search input box. So in this case, it would be a date like 03/10/2016. It then splits it so that the actual value of yyymmdd = 2016. From there, it puts it on the end of a date that would equal the first of the year and the last day of the year.

Where the problem lies is that I do not believe that it is properly detecting whether the date is between beginning and end because it returns values that match the cowed but doesn't take into consideration the date factor.

Comment: Where is this "query" activity? All this code does is build an object and stringify it.

Comment: @Pointy after testing it with out the return stringify, I get the same results as before.

Comment: Where are you actually comparing the date to the beginning and end?  In any case, as you have taken the year from the variable and created the year beginning and year end dates with the same year value, the variable date will have to fall between the two limits.

Comment: @sideroxylon The variable 'name', which determines the year I want to match, comes from local storage. I have specifically made sure that the year value is different that any results that could be found just for testing purposes.

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted has anything at all to do with a "query". The code builds a data structure and returns it as a JSON string; that's it. If that string is subsequently sent to some other mechanism, then you'll have to describe that. If you're expecting that code to magically perform some selection from somewhere, it won't.

Comment: @Pointy My apologies. I am using a platform called Appery.io and this is how they set it up in their services. It is sent to another mechanism, if you will that runs the code and searches a database based on the part of the code that starts with the 'whereObject' variable.